# Analytics - Tracking actions per user

Tags: analytics, tracking

One of our customers has a web application that requires login, and they would like to get Google Analytics to track it per user - to know which users came to their site.
From what I read on Google forums, Google [doesn't](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=55c9c42c15c71581&hl=en&search_impression_id=a6a255fe12be7dd5%3A125b5f524ce) [support](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=6e35b8ee257a9899&hl=en&search_impression_id=a6a255fe12be7dd5%3A125b5f524ce) such tracking.
I was wondering:
a) Do I understand correctly that Google doesn't support that?
b) Does anyone know of a analytics tool that *does* support such action? The only one I've found was [Pmetrics](http://pmetrics.performancing.com/) (which is [Clicky](http://www.getclicky.com/)??), but I would like to have something to compare it to, or if someone who uses this feature on Clicky/Pmetrics could tell me how well it works (there's no demo for this feature on their site)

Comment: Important to realize that this does indeed break Google's privacy policy. You should consider another analytics tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I suspect you could use the [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html) feature of GA and create very granular variables to track on.  Whilst I think you could probably implement some code as per below (modified from the google examples), I'm not sure I'd recommend it as a good idea.

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar( 
      1,                // This custom var is set to slot #1 
      "MemberID",       // The name of the custom variable 
      "12345678",       // The member id value, could read from a query param  
      1                 // Sets the scope to visitor-level 
 ); 
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

As I said though, definitely consider whether it is valuable tracking individuals in such granularity - considering privacy and practical reporting considerations.

Answer (score 8):

From the Google Analytics [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html):

> **You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service
>   to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an
>   individual** (such as a name, email address or billing information), or
>   other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by
>   Google. You will have and abide by an appropriate Privacy Policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws and regulations relating to the
>   collection of information from Visitors. You must post a Privacy
>   Policy and that Privacy Policy must provide notice of Your use of
>   cookies that are used to collect traffic data, and You must not
>   circumvent any privacy features (e.g., an opt-out) that are part of
>   the Service.

So, don't track user accounts in Analytics.

Comment: tracking by a unique id that only you as the provider can correlate with personal data - does not fall under these terms ---- from the terms: "other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google"

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Piwki](http://piwik.org/) and create a plugin to track users. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: You should use Piwik [Custom Variables](http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/) which you can use to track User logins directly

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to capture the userid i.e a numerical id and not the actual usernames then this does not break the Google TOC's as the userid cannot is private to your organisation.

Answer (score 3):

Although custom variables would be helpful, they cannot provide anything more than the number of visits to ALL pages , by a particular user in the site. If you really want good analytics, like each person view per page, TRY THE OLD FASHIONED way of EVENTS.

Example :

```
_trackEvent("Page View", "<YOUR_USER_NAME>", opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

Go to All Website Data -> Content -> Events  -> Pages -> Select any page -> Person View to view and verfiy analytics for each person.

Also you can add additional data in the opt_label and opt_value coulmns.